# There's no implicit reference conversation from T to TBase<ChildBase>

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have two different classes deriving from one base class. They each have a collection deriving from another base class, but different derived class.

```
class MasterA : MasterBase<ClientA>
class MasterB : MasterBase<ClientB>

public class MasterBase<ClientClass> where ClientClass : ClientBase
{
    public List<ClientClass> Clients;
} 

Class ClientA : ClientBase
Class ClientB : ClientBase

Class ClientBase
```

What I want is to have a UserControl which works with the parent/child lists of both Master/Client of either type (A or B).

```
public class Test<MasterClass> where MasterClass : MasterBase<ClientBase>
{
    GenericRepository<MasterClass> repo = new GenericRepository<MasterClass>();
    MasterClass master = repo.GetAll;
    // do some changes to (base fields of) the master collection and its client collection !
    repo.SaveOrUpdate(master);
}
```

But.... I can't instantiate that Test class..

```
var t = new Test<MasterA>();
>> There's no implicit reference conversation from MasterA to MasterBase<ClientBase>
```

So, is there some way I can modify the Test class to be able to do what I've indicated? 
  would really appreciate some hints.

Comment: Would `public class Test<MasterClass,U> where MasterClass : MasterBase<U> where U: ClientBase` be a suitable change to your codebase? (And, obviously, `var t = new Test<MasterA,ClientA>();`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever; Thanks! :) That works as I hoped. I'll accept if you make it an answer.

Comment: done (and expanded with a bit of explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing what constraints you were working under, originally posted this as a comment.

Would

```
public class Test<MasterClass,U> where MasterClass : MasterBase<U> where U: ClientBase
```

be a suitable change to your codebase? Obviously, this line would have to change also:

```
var t = new Test<MasterA,ClientA>();
```

The issue is that, just because there is an inheritance relationship between two classes, `X` and `Y`, that does not mean that the generic types `G<X>` and `G<Y>` have the same (or any) inheritance relationship. So `MasterBase<ClientA>` does *not* inherit from `MasterBase<ClientBase>`

Answer (score 2):

Your trying to go from a more specific generic to a less specific generic in a way that would break type safety.

I changed your types to represent Cats and Dogs, hopefully this will demonstrate the problem:

```
void Main()
{

    Test<AnimalList<Animal>> t = new Test<CatList>();
    t.List.Add(new Cat());
    //You just dogged a cat!
    t.List.Add(new Dog());

    //Change your t to something like:
    Test<AnimalList<Animal>> t = new Test<AnimalList<Animal>>();
    t.List.Add(new Cat());
    //You just dogged an *animal* that's perfectly ok!
    t.List.Add(new Dog());
}

public class Test<TAnimalList> where TAnimalList : AnimalList<Animal>
{
    public TAnimalList List { get; set; }
}

public class CatList : AnimalList<Cat> {}
public class DogList : AnimalList<Dog> {}

public class AnimalList<TAnimal> : List<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal
{
} 

public class Cat : Animal 
{
    public override void Speak() { "Meow".Dump(); }
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void Speak() { "Woof".Dump(); }
}

public abstract class Animal 
{
    public abstract void Speak();
}
```

Moving back to your example, if compiles ( I dont know if its what you want though ) if you change it to:

```
var t = new Test<MasterBase<ClientBase>>();
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually what i needed was to pass fully derived parent/child to the class, in order to work with the repository(I believe). But your code was a good tutorial/learn, I'll review my class design with this in mind.